# My python function won't write to a file

Tags: python

I've made a function for a flask application to create a decorator and a function and then write them to a file but when I run it, it doesn't create a file and write to it and it doesn't return any errors.

```
def make_route(title):
    route = "@app.route(/%s)" %(title)
    def welcome():
        return render_template("%s.html" %(title))
    return welcome
    f = open('test1.txt', 'w')
    f.write(route, '/n', welcome, '/n')
    f.close()

make_route('Hi')
```

Comment: It looks like you're returning before you write the file.

Comment: `return` stops the execution of the function, so everything after it, will not be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`return` statement](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) terminates execution of the function, so any code after it is ignored. Also, `write` writes a string, not random objects. You want:

```
def make_route(title):
    route = "@app.route(/%s)" %(title)
    def welcome():
        return render_template("%s.html" %(title))

    with open('test1.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('%r\n%r\n' % (route, welcome))

    return welcome

make_route('Hi')
```

Comment: Just curious (and this is probably more aimed at OP since it was how he programmed it originally), but what is the purpose of the function in a function? Doe sit actually get called twice as I suspect it does (once at the end of the initial write and again at the return of the `make_route` function

Comment: @Madivad yes it will be used again, it's for making a url route with flask it will be called again when someone goes to the url. Thanks for the help phihag.

Answer (score 1):

I would use philhag answer but use %s instead of %r or you'll write a string, and you could use .**name** if you want to use the function more than once(Which you probably do).

```
def make_route(title):
    route = "@app.route('/%s')" %(title)
    def welcome():
        return render_template("%s.html" %(title))

    with open('test2.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write('%s\n%s\n' % (route, welcome))
    welcome.__name__ = title
    return welcome

make_route('Hi')
```